# How to know which year a LP was pressed?

Tags: vinyl, album

I have an unopened LP, how can I know which year it was pressed and what it's worth without opening it?

Answer (score 2):

On [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com) you can see all the releases by catalog number (which should be on the outside of the sleeve), and see who is offering these for sale. Depending on the version, people are asking $50 - $2000 for this LP. Of course that doesn't mean people are actually paying $2000.